# serverを停止する方法がわからない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

お世話になります。
Railsのserverが動きません。
以前nodejsを使用していたのでもしかしたらそのせいかと思います。
nodejsの方を止めたいのですが、わかりません。VirtualboxでCentOSを使用しています。

コンソール（Railsでのエラー）

```
   Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"db/test.pg"}
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

コンソール

```
4     0  2395  1313  20   0  96080  3816 unix_s Ss   ?          0:00 sshd: vagrant [priv]
5   501  2397  2395  20   0  96080  2168 poll_s S    ?          0:00 sshd: vagrant@pts/0
0   501  2398  2397  20   0 112632  2028 wait   Ss   pts/0      0:00 -bash
1     0  2425     1  20   0  17296   652 rt_sig Ss   ?          0:00 /usr/sbin/anacron -s
0   501  2439  2398  20   0 108128  1032 -      R+   pts/0      0:00 ps alx
```

kill 2439で削除できなかったのですがどうしたらよいのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: netstatでport使ってるprocess探してkill。
psでnode探してkill。

まずは、何のos使ってるかくらい書かないと止め方の書きようがありませんね。

Comment: VirtualboxでCentOSを使用していました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: コンソール(node.js)とはなんでしょうか？あと、killコマンドの指定も違いますし、そもそも出力結果にnode.jsがいません。centosのバージョンも書いていませんし、とりあえず@豚吐露 さんのおっしゃる通り、netstat -tanpかlsof -i:5432を実行してみてください。（なんだかnode.jsは関係ない気がします…）

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQLへの接続に失敗しています。PostgreSQLが起動しているか、ネットワーク経由での接続が出来るよう設定されているか確認してください。

Answer (score 0):

node.jsは無実で、他に原因があるように思います。

/var/log/audit/audit.logにAVCが出ていないですか？
CentOSをどうやってインストールしたのか不明ですが、配布元にあるものはapacheがポートを能動オープンすることはSELinuxのポリシーで許可されていない状態でインストールされるので、DBに接続したい場合自分で許可する必要があります。

CentOS7だと

```
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

を試されてはいかがでしょうか。